# Is a VGG-based CNN model sometimes better for image classfication than a modern architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have an image classification task to solve, but based on quite simple/good terms:

- There are only two classes (either good or not good)
- The images always show the same kind of piece (either with or w/o fault)
- That piece is always filmed from the same angle & distance
- I have at least 1000 sample images for both classes

So I thought it should be easy to come up with a good CNN solution - and it was. I created a VGG16-based model with a custom classifier (Keras/TF). Via transfer learning I was able to achieve up to 100% validation accuracy during model training, so all is fine on that end.

Out of curiosity and because the VGG-based approach seems a bit "slow", I also wanted to try it with a more modern model architecture as base, so I did with *ResNet50v2* and *Xception*. I trained it similar to the VGG-based model, tried it with several hyperparameter modifications etc. However, I was not able to achieve a better validation accuracy then 95% - so much worse than with the "old" VGG architecture.

Hence my question is: Given these "simple" (always the same) images and only two classes, is the VGG model probably a better base than a modern network like ResNet or Xception? Or is it more likely that I messed something up with my model or simply got the training / hyperparameters not right?

Comment: Is your inference time reduced after you training on resnet or xception?

Comment: No not really, with ResNet it's even slower to classify one image.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your specific question here, but I would recommend trying a different architecture for the top layers of VGG. Most of the parameters on VGG nets are in the last few fully connected layers. If you remove all those layers and put in a global maxpooling layer followed by one fully connected layer, you'll end up with a way smaller net that should be significantly faster without sacrificing too much accuracy. It may not work, but I'd say it's worth a shot.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat For the recrods, I would asume that my classifier / custom model head is quite simple. It's just one Flatten() layer, followed by a Dense(256) layer, followed by a Dense(2) layer. That's it.